# SELECT HTML não atualiza após receber dados (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs

Eu tenho um *select* HTML em meu projeto e utilizo o AngularJS

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-3">
    <label>Natureza Operação:</label>
    <select ng-model="comprasConsumivelUnico.compras.naturezaEntrada" ng-change="replaceCtbOperacao(comprasConsumivelUnico.compras.naturezaEntrada, natureza)" ng-options="nat.Natureza as nat.Natureza +' - '+ nat.DescNatureza for nat in natureza | orderBy:'DescNatureza'" ng-required="true">
        <option value="">Selecione Natureza</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Então realizo uma solicitação no banco e ele adiciona o valor 200 para o meu `ng-model ng-model="comprasConsumivelUnico.compras.naturezaEntrada"` este possui o valor, porém o seletor fica com o valor padrão ao invés de ficar o valor da `ng-model`.

[image: Como fica o select html quando realizo uma consulta]

Então após eu simplesmente passar um TAB sobre ele ele atribui o valor correto:

[image: Select após simplesmente passar o TAB]

Gostaria de, ao consultar um pedido, trazer a informação no `select` do valor que veio do banco.

Podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, poderia remover a concatenação da string, e utilizar apenas a segunda parte.

Seu código atual:

```
ng-options="nat.Natureza as nat.Natureza +' - '+ nat.DescNatureza for nat in natureza | orderBy:'DescNatureza'"
```

Uma possível solução:

```
ng-options="nat.DescNatureza for nat in natureza | orderBy:'DescNatureza'"
```